# tippy.js html content / multiline text

Tags: html, css, tooltip, multiline, tippyjs

I am having problems with tippy.js tooltip and multiline html content. I cannot get the line breaks to work at all. HTML template below:

```
<div id="div_id_criticality" class="form-group">   
  <label for="id_criticality" class="requiredField">
  Criticality<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
  </label>
  <span class="formHelp" tippy-message="tippy-criticality" id="formHelp-criticality"><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i></span>
  <div>
    <select name="criticality" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_criticality">
          
      <option value="">-- Select criticality --</option>

        {% for key, value in criticality.items %}
          <option value="{{ key }}">{{ value }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="tippy-criticality" class="tippy-multiline" style="display: none;">
  Line 1<br>
  Line 2<br>
  Line 3<br>
  Line 4
</div>

<script>
  tippy('#formHelp-criticality', {
    content(reference) {
    const id = reference.getAttribute('tippy-message');
    const template = document.getElementById(id);
    return template.innerHTML;
    allowHTML=true;
    }
  });
</script>
```

I also have CSS file containing:

```
.tippy-multiline {
    white-space:pre !important;
}
```

Also tried:

```
.tippy-multiline {
    white-space:pre-wrap !important;
}
```

What happens is that the tooltip shows single line of text "Line 1< br>Line 2< br>Line 3< br>Line 4".

What I am missing here?

Comment: try move the "allowHTML=true;" outside of the last "}" and add a "," after the last "}"

Comment: This didn't do the trick.

Comment: i did a codepen, here is the link https://codepen.io/essenken/pen/wvxeoEO